# Display SqLite Select value in textfield

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to display SQLite table value in text field. This is my code, but it's not working. I have table(SAP_DRQ_TABLE ) with two fields(SAP_DRQ_KEY_METROLAC ,SAP_DRQ_KEY_DRC).

DBHelper.java

```
private static final String SAP_DRQ_TABLE = "sap_drq";
public static final String SAP_DRQ_KEY_METROLAC = "metrolac";
public static final String SAP_DRQ_KEY_DRC= "drc";

public List<SAP_DRQDatamodel> SAP_DRQDatamodel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<SAP_DRQDatamodel> drc = new ArrayList<SAP_DRQDatamodel>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + SAP_DRQ_TABLE +" where"+SAP_DRQ_KEY_METROLAC+"='50'" ;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                SAP_DRQDatamodel codes = new SAP_DRQDatamodel();
                codes.setdrc(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SAP_DRQ_KEY_DRC)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // returning lables
        return drc;
    }
```

dashbord.java

```
DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
List<SAP_DRQDatamodel> DRQval= db.SAP_DRQDatamodel();
for (SAP_DRQDatamodel DRQ : DRQval){
    mDRQ.setText(DRQ.getdrc());
}
```

SAP_DRQDATAMODEL

```
public class SAP_DRQDatamodel {

    public String getmetrolac() {
        return metrolac;
    }

    public void setmetrolac(String metrolac) {
        this.metrolac = metrolac;
    }

    public String getdrc() {
        return drc;
    }

    public void setdrc(String drc) {
        this.drc = drc;
    }

    public String metrolac="", drc="";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is woth your select query

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + SAP_DRQ_TABLE +" where "+SAP_DRQ_KEY_METROLAC+"='50'"
```

Comment: The OP was missing a **space** after the `WHERE` clause

Comment: Thanks.code working without any errors.but it didn't show correct result.

Comment: @Yasi if my answer helped you then kindly tik it.Thanks.

Comment: Possibly, this field `SAP_DRQ_KEY_METROLAC` is an integer, not a string, in your table. Change to `+ SAP_DRQ_KEY_METROLAC + " = 50"`

Comment: @FrankN.Stein i changed it.but same result.blank textfield

Comment: Well, if your field is an int... then use `codes.setdrc(cursor.getInt`